# Clicking on button opens blank screen

Tags: java, android, button

I'm trying to make a quiz app and everything was working fine until I put in my code for my second button, now when I click start nothing happens and clicking study brings up a black screen. Start is supposed to take the user to a different activity, and study is supposed to take them to a website. Can someone check what's wrong with my code?

```
package com.example.rupin.whosthatpokemon;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class questionactivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_questionactivity);
        Button start = findViewById(R.id.start);
        start.setOnClickListener(
                new Button.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent (getApplicationContext(), one.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
        start = findViewById(R.id.study);
        start.setOnClickListener(
                new Button.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Intent i;
                        i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.pokemon.com/us/pokedex/"));
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                });

    }
    public void goToActivity2 (View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent (this, one.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: you have `btn.setOnClickListener` twice instead of `start.setOnClickListener`

Comment: Voting to close question as typo

Comment: oh i dodnt notice that

Answer (score 1):

As Loris Securo said in the comments, " 
you have `btn.setOnClickListener` twice instead of `start.setOnClickListener`". That means you never set the onClickListener of your start button.

Also, in the second onClickListener, you have:

```
i = new Intent(view.getContext(), one.class);
```

You should instead do:

```
i = new Intent(questionactivity.this, one.class);
```

Although `view.getContext()` should technically work, I always seen `this` used as the first parameter in the Intent constructor which is a `Context` object. Since `this` (an instance of an `Activity`) can be cast to a `Context`, it is better to get the context of the outer class , and this would explain why you get a black screen when trying to go to the other activity.

Side note: Your class names should start with a capital letter and be CamelCased such as `ClassOne` or `QuestionActivity`.

Comment: thank you, but now whenever the button is clicked the app just crashes

Comment: @Victini That would be expected if you are using the incorrect `Context`. I just said "black screen" because that's what you said happened in your question.

Comment: Ok so i edited the code, but now it's being funky again, and i'm getting black screen again and
 i = new Intent(questionactivity.this, one.class);
isn't helping either